# Opengl error 1281 when trying to glUseProgram

Tags: opengl, glsl

Any ideas how I could debug this `opengl` error further? `1281`

I'm loading source from files, compiling, linking and then trying to check for errors after `glUseProgram`

In my object's draw method ..

```
log.info(gl2.glIsProgram(shaderProgram)); // true
gl2.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

int error;
while ((error = gl2.glGetError()) != GL2.GL_NO_ERROR) {
    throw new RuntimeException("glUseProgram" + ": glError " + error);
}
```

Output ..

```
[13:38:08] INFO (IARectangle.java:99) - true
java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: glError 1281
```

This is how I load my shader source, from .glsl files ..

```
Vector<Integer> shaders = new Vector<Integer>();

try {

    shaders.add(compileSource(
        loadSource("shaders/vertexShader.glsl"),
        loadSource("shaders/fragmentShader.glsl")));

    return shaders;

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return shaders;
}

public String[] loadSource(String filename){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String[] { sb.toString() };
}

public final int compileSource(final String[] vertexSource, final String[] fragmentSource) throws Exception {

     vertexShaderProgram;
    int fragmentShaderProgram;
    int shaderProgram;

    // load vertexShader source, compile and verify
    vertexShaderProgram = gl2.glCreateShader(GL2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl2.glShaderSource(vertexShaderProgram, 1, vertexSource, null, 0);
    gl2.glCompileShader(vertexShaderProgram);
    verifyCompile(gl2, vertexShaderProgram);

    // load fragmentShader source, compile and verify
    fragmentShaderProgram = gl2.glCreateShader(GL2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl2.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderProgram, 1, fragmentSource, null, 0);
    gl2.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderProgram);
    verifyCompile(gl2, fragmentShaderProgram);

    shaderProgram = gl2.glCreateProgram();

    gl2.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderProgram);
    gl2.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderProgram);
    gl2.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl2.glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL2.GL_LINK_STATUS, intBuffer);

    if (intBuffer.get(0) != 1){

        String infoLog = null;
        gl2.glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL2.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, intBuffer);
        int size = intBuffer.get(0);
        log.error("Program link error: ");
        if (size > 0) {

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
            gl2.getGL2().glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, size, intBuffer, byteBuffer);
            byte[] sizeBytes = new byte[size];
            byteBuffer.get(sizeBytes, 0, size);
            infoLog = new String(sizeBytes);

            log.error("info: " + infoLog);

        } else {
            log.error("Unknown");
        }
        System.exit(1);
        return shaderProgram;

    } else {

        return shaderProgram;
    }
}
```

Vertex shader source ..

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    //gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader source ..

```
#version 120

uniform vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Comment: `1281` = `0x0501` = `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, so double check your function arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance, I'm not sure why `glGetError` is returning an error code.  But to answer your specific question of 'How can I debug this error further?', I do have a suggestion.

Change your draw code to this:

```
// Logging errors before the call to glUseProgram
int error;
while ((error = gl2.glGetError()) != GL2.GL_NO_ERROR) {
    log.info(error);
}

log.info(gl2.glIsProgram(shaderProgram)); // true
gl2.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

int error;
while ((error = gl2.glGetError()) != GL2.GL_NO_ERROR) {
    throw new RuntimeException("glUseProgram" + ": glError " + error);
}
```

Note that the difference here is we've added a block of code to log errors returned by `glGetError` *before* the call to `glUseProgram`.  The reason is because **the error is not necessarily originating in your call to `glUseProgram`**.  If you see the 1281 error logged using the code above, you can determine that the error is actually originating from an OpenGL call made before the `glUseProgram` call.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetError.xml) for `glGetError`:

> glGetError returns the value of the error flag. Each detectable error
>   is assigned a numeric code and symbolic name. When an error occurs,
>   the error flag is set to the appropriate error code value. **No other
>   errors are recorded until glGetError is called, the error code is
>   returned, and the flag is reset to GL_NO_ERROR.**

So, if one of your earlier OpenGL calls (perhaps something in your `compileSource` function, for example) recorded the `1281` error, and you did not call `glGetError` anywhere between that point and your call to `glUseProgram`, you can not reasonably assume that the error is actually originating from the `glUseProgram` call.

In summary, `glGetError` does not return the most recent error recorded by an OpenGL call.  You need to call `glGetError` with more granularity in order to pinpoint where the error is originating.  This will allow you to troubleshoot the issue you're having and determine exactly which OpenGL call is recording the error.

Comment: Thanks @dogjones I've moved the call to `glGetError` before the call to `glUseProgram` and the error is also there. What I've noticed though is that `1281` is continually being printed. Shouldn't the value be reset after I've called `glGetError` the first time? as you mention.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if the drawing code sample you posted is being executed between `glBegin` and `glEnd` calls.  That wouldn't make too much sense though.   If the sample we are discussing IS between `glBegin` and `glEnd` calls, you should know that both `glGetError` and `glUseProgram` result in undefined behavior when called between `glBegin` and `glEnd`.  I recommend moving the code sample to before the `glBegin` call in this case.

Comment: I dont have `glBegin` or `glEnd` in any drawing code

Comment: As far as I know the behavior you're seeing does not conform to the standard, might be an issue with JOGL.  I guess the next thing I'd try is to see how early the error is reported in your program.